# Secure Data with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am making a website and wish to store the data of users that log in into a SECURE database.; their username, URL, profile picture and points.

I am currently working on and studying game development so don't plan on spending too much time learning complex new coding languages. It was recently suggested to me that I learn Ruby on Rails, rather than mySQL and object oriented PHP. I currently have half a website built with HTML that uses some PHP (not coded by me).

Using Rails, can I set up a secure database to store information that can be accessed and changed by the website but untouchable to users?

Comment: Please only ask a single question at a time.  If 3 people answer a different question, which one would you accept?  Also, "would X be the best" software is considered a "subjective" question and is officially off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm relatively new to RoR as well but I'll do my best to answer completely:

1. Rails did have a bit of a learning curve for me, it doesn't help that the language changes so often so that tutorials are out of date quickly. It is very rewarding, however, and will let you quickly create awesome web-apps.
2. Rails has many Gems that you can use for many different things. For user authentication/encryption, you can use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), I've never needed database encryption on its own but I'm sure there are gems for that as well.
3. Rails readily accepts your html if you split it up correctly.  I recommend you use Rails without php to make your own life easier but [Here](http://voormedia.com/blog/2013/10/running-rails-and-php-on-the-same-website) is a guide to run both if you really need to.

Hope this helps.